# Get information about a file with c in linux

Tags: c, linux, sockets

When I run:

```
ls -l /proc/123/fd/80
```

I can see for example:

```
89-> socket:[38676]
```

How can I get this information in C? How can I know that this `fd` point to a socket/pipe and get the number inside the brackets (the `38676` between `[ ]`)

By the way, is the number between brackets the size of buffer's socket?

Comment: The `fstat()` syscall is a good starting point.

Comment: @Shawn , and how can I know witch Ip this socket binded?

Comment: The functionality you're looking for is already available in command line tools like [fport](https://www.ghacks.net/2009/02/03/fport-maps-ports-to-applications/) and [netstat](https://linux.die.net/man/8/netstat).  If you want to use this functionality from a C program (or if you want to read the values of `/proc/123/fd/80` from a C program, then use [popen](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html).

Comment: You'd use [`getsockname()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getsockname.2.html) for that.

Comment: @Shawn getsockname() doesn't help me, that works only if this command run in the same process's context

Answer (score 0):

[man fstat](https://linux.die.net/man/2/fstat) will give you all the documentation you need.

The man page gives an example you can easily adapt:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct stat sb;

    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <pathname>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (stat(argv[1], &sb) == -1) {
        perror("stat");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (S_IFSOCK != (sb.st_mode & S_IFMT)) {
        printf("Not a socket.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("socket: %ld\n", (long) sb.st_ino);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Can I check with C if that socket is client/server?? Or the last time this socket get data?